# Not able to addEventlistner?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I seem to be having an issue adding an eventlistner to my YT.player.

```
var ytapi = document.createElement('script');
ytapi.src = "https://ww" + "w.youtube" + ".com/iframe_api";
var scriptref = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
scriptref.parentNode.insertBefore(ytapi, scriptref);
window.players = [];

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    switch(event.data) {
        case YT.PlayerState.ENDED:
            alert('VIDEO IS ENDED');

        case YT.PlayerState.CUED:
            alert('VIDEO IS CUED');

        case YT.PlayerState.PAUSED:
            alert('VIDEO IS PAUSED'); 
            break;
    }
};

window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    jQuery('iframe[src*="youtube.com"]').each(function() {
        var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        window.players[id] = new YT.Player(id);
        window.players[id].addEventListener('onStateChange','onPlayerStateChange');
    });
};
```

OnStateChange is not being triggered, but

If i in the browser console do

```
window.players[id].addEventListener('onStateChange','test');
function test(event){alert(event.data)};
```

It works?

Aren't I doing the exact same in the code? so why does it only work in console?

Comment: `addEventListener(<string>, <string>)` doesn't exist. You should pass a function as second parameter

Comment: `addEventListener('onStateChange', test);`

Comment: trying to say it works when i do it consone, not in code.. test is just a test function.. want to use the other...

Comment: @CristianTraìna it is a function, defined above...

Comment: @CristianTraìna The console command works as expected..

Answer (score 1):

That happens because `addEventListener(<string>, <string>)` isn't a function, as stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

As you can read, about the second parameter of the method:

> This must be an object implementing the EventListener interface, or a JavaScript function. See The event listener callback for details on the callback itself.

So a string isn't accepted. Probably you meant to pass the `test` function variable reference, and not the `test` string.

So, just drop quotes:

```
addEventListener('onStateChange', test);
```

Note: Some javascript functions also accept strings in place of functions, such as `eval` and `setTimeout`. But the use is discouraged